# Is it possible to integrate Live Agent with a Chatbot?

Tags: integration, liveagent

The goal is to have a Chatbot taking incoming chats instead of a real agent, it will provide instructions and only if the customer still needs additional assistance, it will redirect him to a real agent.

Is it even possible to implement this with the current Live Agent API? 
Are there any 3rd party vendors who offer something similar?

Comment: Please research this on appexchange for any 3rd party tools . But looks like api's are availble as per this doc https://tutorials.botsfloor.com/creating-a-simple-chatbot-in-salesforce-lightning-using-api-ai-in-less-than-60-mins-4dd79777b246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Neuraflash Intelligent Chatbot](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EcqdSUAR) on the appexchange.  It leverages NLPS engines such as Google Dialogue Flow, Amazon Lex, and IMB Watson and will escalate conversations to Live Agent.